# Display image as alert

Tags: javascript, image

I know this is a very simple question but I have the following code which currently (after the user has clicked to submit the form) displays a pop-up with my img src path, how can i change to display the actual image within the pop-up and not the path?

```
echo '
<img src="../mypath/to/the/image.jpg" id="form-submit">
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(document.getElementById("form-submit").src);
</script>
';
```

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** display an image on the native JS alert dialog box nor you can change the title, style etc of it.

If you are looking for such options , you should go for the [`JQuery Dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. You _think_ ? So why don't you suggest some links or help the OP instead of assumptions ?

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at JQuery Dialog! :)

Comment: http://cameronbaney.com/tutorials/css3modal/# and http://dailysyntax.com/10-great-css3-modal-box-without-javascript/

Comment: @JasonOOO, That is irrelevant to JS Alert Box. Can you read properly what I wrote as an answer ? Karina was trying to put the image on the Native JS dialog box which is **definitely not possible** and what you are suggesting is an _alternate_ way. like the `JQuery Dialog`... That's all.